# Liquid cooling system for Emrax 208 motor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cooling

I am on a student design team planning to build an electric motorcycle and we are planning to use an EMRAX 208 motor. We want to have liquid cooling for the motor but I cannot find any resources on where to buy the cooling system. Are there any companies that deal with this sort of stuff? If not, do you have any suggestions on how to make a cooling system? Thank you for your help in advance

Note: I am not asking for you to tell me which one to purchase, I am just trying to be directed in the right direction. Also this is my first time asking a question here so I apologize in advance if I break rules.

Comment: What are your specification for the liquid cooling system?

Comment: The user manual says to have 7L/min with a pressure drop of 0.6 bar. Pressure drop must not be greater then 2 bar

Comment: So spec it yourselves... what is the power of the motor? What is the efficiency? How much is wasted heat? Now you have to spec a radiator for about that amount of heat - except some goes out the exhaust and other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should design a cooling system according to the [motor manual](https://emrax.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/user_manual_for_emrax_motors.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A36%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C47%2C732%2C0%5D) (this is just one I found, make sure you use the correct manual).

Before you get into liquid cooling, make sure that the air cooling requirements cannot be satisfied.
The motor doesn't perform any worse with air cooling, as long as you can meet the requirements.

For the liquid cooling system, start by determining the required coolant flow and heat dissipation.
Use that to spec a pump and a heat exchanger (probably a radiator).
The radiator might be passively cooled or have fans.

The cooling section in the manual provides design requirements and guidelines for either cooling method.
Make absolutely sure that your cooling system meets requirements, or you might have warranty problems.

If you do design a liquid cooling system, you should consider using it to cool other systems, such as batteries.
You may not have any other systems that need active cooling, but it can simplify your design if you do.

Comment: So are you assuming that all the systems run between the same temperature limits?

Comment: @SolarMike not necessarily, but it's worth determining of they can be combined. I doubt that anything on the motorcycle would require a high-temperature cooling loop, especially because it's an electric motorcycle, which I doubt depends on the running components hitting a specific steady-state temperature